# Equations $ax^2+btx+c=0, bx^2+ctx+a=0$ and $cx^2+atx+b=0$

Tags: quadratics

> Find different real numbers $a,b,c,t$ for which the following conditions:
>
> *1)* the equation $ax^2+btx+c=0$ has real roots $x_1,x_2$;
>
> *2)* the equation $bx^2+ctx+a=0$ has real roots $x_2,x_3$;
>
> *3)* the equation $cx^2+atx+b=0$ has real roots $x_1,x_3$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3 -$ different real numbers.

**My work so far:**

I use [Vieta's_formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas):

Obviously $abc\not=0$. Then $$(x_1x_2)(x_2x_3)(x_3x_1)=\frac ca \cdot\frac ab \cdot\frac bc=1.$$
Then $$x_1x_2x_3=\pm1$$

*I don't know how to solve more*

Comment: I think you are given $x_1,x_2,x_3$ to find $a,b,c,t$, not the other way around.

Comment: Try to work out the following cases:
1) $a+b+c=0$
2) $a=b$ or any two of them is equal
3) if all are different, 
$$
a^2-a b t^2-a c+b^2-b c+c^2 t^2=0
$$
and all symmetric versions hold, but then $a=b=c=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Vieta's formulas,
$$x_1+x_2=-\frac{bt}{a},\quad x_1x_2=\frac ca$$
$$x_2+x_3=-\frac{ct}{b},\quad x_2x_3=\frac ab$$
$$x_3+x_1=-\frac{at}{c},\quad x_3x_1=\frac bc$$

From these, we can have
$$-t=(x_1+x_2)x_2x_3=(x_2+x_3)x_3x_1=(x_3+x_1)x_1x_2,$$
i.e.
$$-t=x_1x_2x_3+x_2^2x_3=x_1x_2x_3+x_3^2x_1=x_1x_2x_3+x_1^2x_2$$
from which we have
$$x_2^2x_3=x_3^2x_1=x_1^2x_2$$
Since $x_1x_2x_3\not=0$, 
$$x_2^2=x_3x_1\quad\text{and}\quad x_3^2=x_1x_2$$
Eliminating $x_3$ gives
$$\left(\frac{x_2^2}{x_1}\right)^2=x_1x_2$$
to get
$$(x_1-x_2)\left(\left(x_1+\frac{x_2}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3x_2^2}{4}\right)=0$$
from which we have $x_1=x_2$ since $x_1,x_2$ are real numbers.

So there is no such $(a,b,c,t,x_1,x_2,x_3)$.